# How to set thread priority in RTLinux?

Tags: rtos

How to set thread priority in RTLinux? Also, what is the range of priority levels; which is highest priority and which is lowest?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887531/which-real-time-priority-is-the-highest-priority-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

The command `renice -n <prio> <pid>` will adjust the niceness of a thread or process.  The values for 'prio' range from -20 (best for the process) to 19 (worst for the process).

Comment: I'm guessing RTLinux has a separate notion of thread priority, which is set using a specific tool.

Comment: It's been a while so I may be confusing various projects I've worked on but I'm pretty sure that's how I did it last time I used RTLinux

Comment: Oh, OK, then you must know much better than me. I was assuming things about systems I know almost nothing about.